# Always have my Image show in X percentage using CSS?

Tags: css

I have an image that I want to resize on my websites rendering using CSS.

I can't use Width because that would cause it to be a fixed size, so what should I use? Can I use a percentage? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague. Can you give some more details of what you're trying to do?

Can you not do something like the following?

In your HTML:

```
<html>
    ... <img src='somewhere/someimage.png' class='myImg' />
</html>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.myImg {
    width: 20%;
}
```